# ActiveRecord autosave:false doesn't appear to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autosave

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html), setting `:autosave => false` on an association should NOT save those associations when you save the parent.  This doesn't appear to work for me.  I just created a vanilla Rails 3.0.8 app and here's what I get:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, :autosave => false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

f = Foo.new :name => 'blah', :bars_attributes => [{:name => 'lah'},{:name => 'lkjd'}]
f.save
f.bars
 => [#<Bar id: 1, name: "lah", foo_id: 1, created_at: "2011-06-20 20:51:02", updated_at: "2011-06-20 20:51:02">, #<Bar id: 2, name: "lkjd", foo_id: 1, created_at: "2011-06-20 20:51:02", updated_at: "2011-06-20 20:51:02">]
```

What??  Why did it save the `bars`?

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!!  What am I missing?

*Update: It appears as if `accepts_nested_attributes_for` automatically saves children, even if they're not built using the nested attributes feature.  It think this is a bug.*

Comment: What's the output of `f.bars.first.new_record?` after you run your given code?

Comment: i've output `f.bars` above.  It's obvious that `new_record?` would return false as it's been persisted with an ID.  Again this only happens when `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is used

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug, instead it is intended. see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

A click on "Source: show" on method accepts_nested_attributes_for also proves this.

> Note that the :autosave option is automatically enabled on every
>   association that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Innerpeacer response, it doesn't make sense setting the autosave attribute to false if you are using accepts_nested_attributes_for.
One of the reasons to use accepts_nested_attributes_for is to save children and parent at the same time.

What you can do is:

```
f = Foo.new :name => 'blah'
f.save
f.bars_attributes = [{:name => 'lah'},{:name => 'lkjd'}]
```

or

```
f = Foo.new :name => 'blah'
f.save
f.bars = [Bars.new({:name => 'lah'}), Bars.new({:name => 'lkjd'})]
```